# Deleting/Disabling JAR in plugin's folder of Eclipse using JAVA code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any way to delete or disable JAR present in the plugin's folder of Eclipse using JAVA code written in Eclipse?

Comment: To remove it from the install you would use the [Eclipse Provisioning Platform (p2)](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_overview.htm) in an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Can we remove or uninstall by using a JAVA code written in the same eclipse @greg-449? Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes the p2 API runs in the 'same' Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 Please can you elaborate more on this , my scenario is i have my own plugin which i have pasted in the plugin's folder of eclipse and i want that not to work after some days like we have subscriptions of some software type. Can you help on this please? Appreciate your Help.

Comment: I am not an expert on the p2 Platform.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you so much for your help. I will research into it and see its feasibility.